# how can i use newline character with Imagick::annotateImage()?

Tags: imagick

```
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps\n over the lazy dog');
```

Imagick::annotateImage() seems do not work with newline \n, does it support use this \n charater?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the \n with \ so it becomes \\n

Comment: Try:  $image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, "The quick brown fox jumps\n over the lazy dog");